# I hava a maze search algorithm and is not stopping at end point an is also printing unwanted nodes

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I would appreciate any help...

I have 2 maze search algorithms which are DFS and BFS. The starting point is set at 0 and end point is set at 1. The nodes are placed in a stack and starts visiting its neighbors to find the path to 1. The nodes that are not involved in the path to 1 should be erased which is not happening. And also when the path finds the goal which is 1 it is not stopping.
Basically the testMaze path should be 0 5 4 1 whereas BFS is giving me 0 3 5 0 2 11 4 7 1 6 8 9 10  and 
DFS is giving me 0, it initiates and it never finds anything. I think the problem might lie in either the printNode function or the visited, isVisited.

Below are the methods related to these problems. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import java.util.*;



public class Maze {


public Node startingNode;
public ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
public int[][] matrix = new int[100][100];


// to set starting node at 0 
public void setStartingNode(Node n) {
    this.startingNode = n;
}

public Node getStartingNode() {
    return this.startingNode;
}

public void addNode(int n) {
    nodes.add(new Node (n));
}

public void visited(int n1) {
    for(Node n2 : nodes) {
        if(n2.list == n1) {
             n2.visited = true;
        }

    } 
}

public boolean isVisited(int n1) {
    for(Node n2 : nodes) {
        if(n2.list == n1) {
            return n2.visited ;
        }

    }
    return false;

}

public Node getNode(int n) {
    for(Node n2 : nodes) {
        if(n2.list == n) {
            return n2;
        }

}
    return new Node(-1);
}

//TODO get the next unvisited node
public Node getNextNode(Node n) {

    int link = n.list;
    int i = 0;                      
    while (i<nodes.size()) {
        if(matrix[link][i] == 1 && isVisited(i) == false)
        {
            return (Node)getNode(i);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return null;

}


//algorithm uses queue and should find all paths
public void bfs() {

    Queue<Node> q=new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(this.startingNode);
    printNode(this.startingNode);
    startingNode.visited=true;
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        Node n=(Node)q.remove();//
        Node child=null;//
        while((child=getNextNode(n))!=null)
        {
            child.visited=true;
            printNode(child);
            q.add(child);
        }
    }
    //Clear visited property of nodes
    clearNodes();

}

// algorithm uses stack and should find fastest solution
public void dfs() {


    Stack<Node> s=new Stack<Node>();
    s.push(this.startingNode);
    startingNode.visited=true;
    printNode(startingNode);
    while(!s.isEmpty())
    {
        Node n=(Node)s.peek();
        Node child=getNextNode(n);
        if(child!=null)
        {
            child.visited=true;
            printNode(child);
            s.push(child);
        }
        else
        {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    //Clear visited property of nodes
    clearNodes();

}
private void clearNodes() {

    int j = 0;
    while (j < 0) {
        Node n = (Node)nodes.get(j);
        n.visited = false;
        j++;
    }

}

// to print nodes 
private void printNode(Node n) {
    System.out.print(n.list + " ");
}

}
```

Below is the main class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// C:\Users\Mannie\Desktop\maze1.txt
// C:\Users\Mannie\Desktop\maze2.txt
// C:\Users\Mannie\Desktop\maze3.txt

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String stringNode;
    File file = new File(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter file path"));
    ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    Maze maze = new Maze();
    maze.setStartingNode(new Node(0));
    // idea is to convert string into 2D arrays here removing substring " " using .split
    try {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                stringNode = sc.nextLine();
                nodes.add(stringNode);

                String[] segment = stringNode.split(" ");
                //for (String val: ){
                    //the first time this loops the value will be 11, the second time it will be 3
                    //i have no idea what you 
                    int intNode1 = Integer.parseInt(segment[0]);
                    int intNode2 = Integer.parseInt(segment[1]);
                    //System.out.println(intNode);
                    maze.matrix[intNode1][intNode2] = 1;
                    maze.matrix[intNode2][intNode1] = 1;


            }

            // nodes
            for (int k=0;k<100;++k)
                maze.nodes.add(new Node(k));
        } 
        finally
        {

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

    Iterator<String> i = nodes.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }


    // To print bfs results
    // also print the system clock time to time the algorithm using
    // System.nanoTime();
    maze.bfs();
    System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println();

    // To print dfs results
    // also print the system clock time to time the algorithm using
    // System.nanoTime();
    maze.dfs();
    System.nanoTime();
}
}
```

Here is the Node class which just passes through the nodes

```
public class Node {
public int list;
public boolean visited = false;
public Node(int node) {
    this.list = node;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
public Node getNode(int n) {
    for(Node n2 : nodes) {
        if(n2.list == n) {
            return n2;
        }
    }
    return new Node(-1);
}
```

you are returning a `new Node(-1);` instead of `null` as you expect here:

```
while((child=getNextNode(n))!=null)
{
    child.visited=true;
    printNode(child);
    q.add(child);
}
```

This causes wrong nodes to be printed and it will not stop. This code was takes from `bfs()` but also applies to `dfs()`. You should return `null` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I tried it and still ended with the same results.

Comment: What I have noticed through debugging is that the algorithm starts checking from the beginning of the test maze and just goes through them again print each unvisited node